# What are best practices for using "display: inline-block"

Tags: css

"Inline-block" and "position" confuse me when I use them with list items. Dreamweaver CS3 isn't helping since it doesn't show the blocks inline but as a stack of elements. I'm interested in learning the **best practices** for getting block elements of various heights to align along their top edges while also centering within the total available space.

Would you please look at this pared-down code to see if I've done it properly?
http://www.words4it.com/test_block1.html

Here's the CSS:
http://words4it.com/test_block1.css

Thank you

Comment: It looks good to me. If you're looking to make the elements lock together even tighter vertically, try [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: Documentation on the CSS `display` property is here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: ... and note that `display: inline-block` is considered a legacy value.

Answer (score 1):

[here is the good article](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) about positioning elements

[here is the good article](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) about element sizes, margins and paddings

and after all, **my short advice** about blocks, inline-blocks and floats:
browser has two general models of aligning elements:

1. **inline model**, blocks stick to each other horizontally making horizontal lines of blocks with line-breaks between blocks, you may think about it like words in the text. Using this model you operate the following properties:

   - font-size
   - line-height
   - text-align
   - vertical-align
   - etc.
2. **block model**, blocks stick to each other vertically making vertical stack of blocks, you may think about it like paragraphs in the text. Using this model you operate the following properties:

   - margin
   - padding
   - float/clear
   - position
   - etc.

The corresponding model should be used when you are trying to achieve the described behaviour. 
There is little exception: several blocks with the same float value (e.g. float:left) can behave very similar to several inline-blocks, the difference is in browser compatibility and thу choise should depend on situation.